MYSQL Update Query Remove part Sting
I and trying to remove part of a string as below
#Crawlers_Album_The_Mess_We_Seem_To_Make #Crawlers<br><br>[center][url=&quot;https://www.databasedreams.co.uk/charts/index.php?action=gallery;sa=view;id=35847&quot;]

#Crawlers_Album_The_Mess_We_Seem_To_Make #Crawlers<br><br>[center][url=&quot;https://www.databasedreams.co.uk/charts/index.php?action=gallery;sa=view;id=35847&quot;][img]https://www.databasedreams.co.uk/charts/gallery/35/medium_1-270224213050-35846450.jpeg[/img][/url]<br>[music_rawards id=-2028986475]Awards[/music_rawards][/center]<br><br>&nbsp; &nbsp;  Released: [color=pink][size=2]16 February 2024[/size][/color]<br>&nbsp; &nbsp;  Cat no: [color=pink][size=2]5827488[/size][/color]<br>&nbsp; &nbsp;  Album Type: [color=pink][size=2]Studio Album[/size][/color]<br><br>[music_rinfo id=-2028986475]Info[/music_rinfo]<br>[music_rstats id=-2028986475]Stats[/music_rstats]

I have tried but messed up and emptied the field
UPDATE `database_messages` 
SET `body`= RIGHT(`body`, INSTR(`body`,'][img]')+1) 
WHERE `id_board` = 128 and INSTR(`body`,'][img]'); 

I was hoping to remove the first part of the string that contains ][img] so the post should look like
[img]https://www.databasedreams.co.uk/charts/gallery/35/medium_1-270224213050-35846450.jpeg[/img][/url]<br>[music_rawards id=-2028986475]Awards[/music_rawards][/center]<br><br>&nbsp; &nbsp;  Released: [color=pink][size=2]16 February 2024[/size][/color]<br>&nbsp; &nbsp;  Cat no: [color=pink][size=2]5827488[/size][/color]<br>&nbsp; &nbsp;  Album Type: [color=pink][size=2]Studio Album[/size][/color]<br><br>[music_rinfo id=-2028986475]Info[/music_rinfo]<br>[music_rstats id=-2028986475]Stats[/music_rstats]

And after I was going to run a replace for [/img][/url] so it removes the [/url] of that section

The problem is that RIGHT() counts from the end, but INSTR() returns the position counting from the beginning. Use SUBSTR() instead.
UPDATE `database_messages` 
SET `body`= SUBSTR(`body`, INSTR(`body`,'][img]')+1) 
WHERE `id_board` = 128 and INSTR(`body`,'][img]');

